# Laravel livewire using several instances of a ckeditor component in the same page

Tags: laravel-livewire, ckeditor5

I have the following livewire component

**controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;


class CkeditorRich extends Component


{
    public $value;
    public $ckeId;
    const EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED = 'cke_rich_value_updated';

    public function mount($value = '')
    {
        $this->value = $value;
         $this->ckeId = 'cke-' . uniqid();
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.ckeditor-rich');
    }
    public function updatedValue($value)
    {
        $this->emit(self::EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED, $this->value);
    }
}
```

**Blade view**

```
<div>
    <div wire:ignore class="form-group row">
        <div class="w-full">
            
            <input id="{{ $ckeId }}" type="hidden" name="value" value="{{ $value }}">
            <textarea wire:model='value' class="form-control required" name="editor" id="editor"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor')

                , {
                    plugins: ['Heading', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Subscript', 'Superscript',
                        'List', 'HorizontalLine',
                        'FontBackgroundColor', 'FontColor', 'FontFamily', 'FontSize', 'RemoveFormat',
                        'SpecialCharacters',
                        'Indent', 'IndentBlock', 'BlockQuote', 'CodeBlock',
                        'Link', 'FindAndReplace', 'HtmlEmbed', 'MediaEmbed', 'Image', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageInsert',
                        'ImageResize', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageCaption',
                        'Autoformat', 'Essentials'
                    ],

                    toolbar: ['heading', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                        'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'horizontalline', '|',
                        'fontbackgroundcolor', 'FontColor', 'fontfamily', 'fontsize', 'removeformat',
                        'specialcharacters', '|',
                        'indent', 'outdent', '|', 'blockQuote', 'codeBlock', ' | ',
                        'link', 'findandreplace', 'htmlembed', 'mediaembed', 'insertimage', '|',
                        'undo', 'redo'
                    ],


                    heading: {
                        options: [{
                                model: 'paragraph',
                                title: 'Paragraph',
                                class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'
                            },
                            {
                                model: 'heading1',
                                view: 'h1',
                                title: 'Heading 1',
                                class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
                            },
                            {
                                model: 'heading2',
                                view: 'h2',
                                title: 'Heading 2',
                                class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
                            },
                            {
                                model: 'heading3',
                                view: 'h3',
                                title: 'Heading 3',
                                class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    image: {
                        toolbar: [

                            'imageStyle:side',
                            'imageStyle:alignRight',
                            'imageStyle:alignLeft',
                            'imageStyle:alignCenter',
                            'imageStyle:alignBlockRight',
                            'imageStyle:alignBlockLeft',
                            '|',

                            'imageTextAlternative',
                            'toggleImageCaption',
                            '|',
                        ]
                    },
                    codeBlock: {
                        languages: [{
                                language: 'css',
                                label: 'CSS'
                            },
                            {
                                language: 'html',
                                label: 'HTML'
                            },
                            // Use the "php-code" class for PHP code blocks.
                            {
                                language: 'php',
                                label: 'PHP',
                                class: 'php-code'
                            },
                        ]
                    }

                })
            .then(editor => {
                editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                    @this.set('value', editor.getData());
                    //console.log('changed');
                    //console.log(editor.getData());

                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('there was a problem : ' + error);
            });
        //var mapp = ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.map(plugin => plugin.pluginName);
        //console.log(mapp);
    </script>

</div>
```

**Use in a create post view**

```
   @livewire('ckeditor-rich',['value'=>$body])
```

**in the post controller**

```
   protected $listeners = [
        ...
        'cke_rich_value_updated' => 'editor_value_updated',
       ...
    ];

    public function editor_value_updated($value)
    {
        $this->body = $value;
    }
```

I want to use 2 instances of this editor to input 2 fiels body and abstract
I am thinking of appending the $ckeId to the textarea Id but **I dont know how to pass this value to the script** in order to write
ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('$editor(something to produce the right id)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually made out that I can use @this.property in the script to get the value of property. Neverthe the less , it was necessary to put the script outside the enclosing div of the ckeditor livewire component.

Then in the create post blade I passed an additional parameter

```
@livewire('ckeditor-rich',['value'=>$abstract,'who'=>'abstract'])
@livewire('ckeditor-rich',['value'=>$body,'who'=>'body'])
```

Whith this, no longer need the ckeId .

I then set the $who property in the ckeditor controller with this new parameter

```
  public $value;
    public $who;
    const EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED = 'cke_rich_value_updated';

    public function mount($value = '',$who='')
    {
        
        $this->value = $value;
         $this->who=$who;
      
    }
```

In the view of the ckeditor component I used the $who property to distinguish the editors

```
<div>
    <div wire:ignore class="form-group row">
        <div class="w-full">
            
            <input  type="hidden" name="value" value="{{ $value }}">
            <textarea wire:model='value' class="form-control required" name="editor" id="editor-{{$who}}"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        var Id=@this.who;
        console.log(ckeId);
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor-'+Id)
...
```

then in the controller of ckeditor component's updatedValue  I passed the $who property in the dispatched event.

```
 public function updatedValue()
    {
        $this->emit(self::EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED, [$this->value,$this->who]);
    }
```

Finally in the post controller I used the $who parameter to set the right property

```
public function editor_value_updated($value)
    {
        if($value[1]==='body'){
             $this->body = $value[0];
        }else{
            $this->abstract=$value[0];
        }
       
    }
```